# OutOfMemory Error while reading data from http Get request android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, http-get, httpservice

I am doing a http Get request. I need to receive huge data, but getting OutOfMemory Exception while reading data.

My code:

```
public static String getData(String url) throws CustomException {
    // http post
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb = null;
    String result = null;
    HttpGet httppost;
    HttpEntity entity;

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        throw new CustomException("Could not establish network connection");
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int c;
        byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
        while ((c = is.read(buffer)) > -1)
            baos.write(buffer, 0, c); //**OutOfMemory Exception.**
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

        is.close();
        result = new String(data, 0, data.length, "utf-8");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        throw new CustomException("Error parsing the response");
    }

    return result;

}
```

URL which I pass to getData is : http://ec2-50-19-105-251.compute-1.amazonaws.com/ad/Upload/getitemlist09122013014749.txt

Please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: there are so many records thats why.. i think you should install app in sdcard or phone storage..

Comment: Dude, the url return lots of data. Don't add it to memory. Use file system.

Answer (score 2):

The received file is large, you need to write the response to file instead of ByteArrayOutputStream, and then try to parse the result from file.

And if possible, the server should split the large file into small chunks.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to implement pagination in fetching the result from server.
After that you can write the data somewhere gradually.